# How to debug IMAPS session?

Tags: ssl, imap

I want to debug IMAPS (port 993) session at client-side, e.g. to see:

- which ciphers client offers to server to use for SSL
- which one does server chooses, or which one are exactly uses during SSL session

I only know how to get the list of ciphers server supports with nmap (`nmap -Pn --script ssl-cert,ssl-enum-ciphers -p 993 imap.example.com`), but how to debug the session? I guess that tcpdump is my goal, but I only could see some encrypted traffic with tcpdumd from client side (`tcpdump -lxX -s 1500 -i eth0 'port 993'`).

Comment: Use wireshark instead. This gives you a more detailed view including details of the ClientHello like the ciphers offered by the client.

Comment: If you have the server's private key you can add that to wireshark and wireshark will decode the stream for you. If you don't have that, then you're out of luck: One goal of SSL is to provide privacy from people who are indistinguishable from you.

Comment: @arnt I'm not asking how to sniff encrypted data - I'm just want to know parameters of SSL session (e.g. cipher type)

Comment: Some of the parameters are available as cleartext (and wireshark will show those right away), others are protected. In my experience just the cleartext is never enough, but I suppose you might be lucky.